# Must contain at least 2 letters

Tags: php, regex

How do I check a string for containing **at least 2 letters in any position/order**? Case-insensitive

This of course only works for one or more letters

```
if (!preg_match('/[a-z]+/i', $pass)) {

}
```

Then I tried something like

```
if (!preg_match('/[a-z]{2,}/i', $pass)) {

}
```

But that doesn't work

Thanks

EDIT: by "any position/order" I mean 12345ab / a12345b / 12a345b6

Comment: Do you want 2 letters back-to-back, like `123az456`? Or just that it contains 2 letters, like `12s45j246`?

Comment: Down-voting without a constructive comment really makes me sick! On the other hand, this is a very useful question and the same applies to the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need this regex:

```
[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yK7sL6/1)

So, your PHP becomes:

```
if(!preg_match("/[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]/i", $pass)) {

}
```

Captain Codeman's solution (`([^a-z]*[a-z]){2,}`) works, but is less efficient, because it requires parsing the entire string, when you just want to know if there are two letters present anywhere in `$pass`.

Comment: Nice one. Gonna have to accept this. Don't hate me CaptainCodeman :D Thumbs up for your solution too

Comment: @mowgli No, that's it man, I added you to my hate list.  Watch your back. ;P

Comment: @CaptainCodeman hehe ;)

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]
```

Or, you could compress it as:

```
([^a-z]*[a-z]){2,}
```

Comment: hm ok, isn't there a more compact way ;)

Comment: How about something like ([^a-z]*[a-z]){2,}

Comment: Last one seems alright, gotta test it some. Change your answer to that ;)

Comment: @hwnd As my question says: How do I check a string for containing at least 2 letters in any position/order? And I like short precise code ;)

Comment: Apparently it does! after a lot of testing ;) I just want to be safe you know

Comment: Testing is sufficient to show the presence of previously unknown errors, but never their absence. Is that guarantee strong enough for you?

Comment: No, I would of course rather have a function that is secure